# swift 2: no delegate callbacks for push notifications as opposed to objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, swift2

I have created 2 sample (single view) projects to test push notifications, I didn't add any code except for the notifications setup code as following:

**Project1 (Swift 2):**

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let settings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Alert, .Badge, .Sound], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerForRemoteNotifications()

    return true
}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings notificationSettings: UIUserNotificationSettings) {

    print("didRegisterUserNotificationSettings got called")

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: NSData) {

    let trimmedDeviceToken = deviceToken.description .stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "<>"))
        .stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
    print("Device Token \(trimmedDeviceToken)")

}

func application(application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: NSError) {
    print("Failed to get token, error: \(error)")
}
```

**Project2 (Objective-C):**

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

UIUserNotificationSettings* notificationSettings =
[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil];

[application registerUserNotificationSettings:notificationSettings];
[application registerForRemoteNotifications];

return YES;
}

  -(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterUserNotificationSettings:(UIUserNotificationSettings *)notificationSettings {

NSLog(@"didRegisterUserNotificationSettings got called");

}

  -(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData*)deviceToken
 {

NSString* newToken = [deviceToken description];
newToken = [newToken stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
newToken = [newToken stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];

NSLog(@"Device Token %@", newToken);
 }

   -(void)application:(UIApplication*)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError*)error
 {
         NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
 }
```

the objective-c project works fine on all tested devices: registers itself for remote notifications and receives a device token in the delegate callback method, **but the swift project couldn’t get any of the delegate callback**s.

read what I’ve tried before marking this question as duplicate:

1) AppID is push notification enabled
2) Push certificate type is production  and Provisioning profile is AdHoc production
3) both projects use the same AppID, push certificate and provisioning profile
4) both projects have been tested on 3 different iPhones (5, 6 & 6Plus) all running iOS 9.2, deleted the app with every install and restarted all of them many times
5) built both projects with Xcode 7.2 on 2 different MAC Pro machines
6) all 3 iPhones use internet connection without a firewall and all ports are open (as stated in [this technical note](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2265/_index.html)), also changed the internet connection on the 3 devices to be a 3G connection instead of a WIFI.
7) checked/unchecked Push Notifications in project settings -> capabilities for both projects (by the way, this point has no effect as i tested it)
8) tried Xcode Run (the top button) and Export ipa package for both projects
9) tried both (application) & ( [UIApplication sharedApplication] for objective-c and UIApplication.sharedApplication() ) for swift with the method registerForRemoteNotifications
10) tried another brand new AppID, push certificate and provisioning profile for both projects.
11) deleted both projects, and created another 2 new projects with the same code as above

the objective-c project after all these tries works fine and receives a device token through didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken method but the swift one does not work.

I have generated 3 APN log files from the iPhone 6Plus device using `PersistentConnectionLogging.mobileconfig` profile by Apple, and [uploaded them here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/uww8aus23xegq6t/AADafR7s9EJnqyFqv7Fzyiw-a?dl=0), (inside `apsd_2016_02_24_11_36_29+0300.log` file the objective-c project BundleID is `XXXXX.push.notification` and the swift project BundleID is `XXXXX.apnsswift` )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it turns out that the reason behind this weird problem is the swift's `print` method which does not show the output in device's log in contrast to `NSLog`, the swift app has no problem, it just need to use `NSLog` to show the messages in Push Notification delegate callback methods.

```
//print("Device Token \(trimmedDeviceToken)")
NSLog("Device Token: %@",trimmedDeviceToken)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you 100% sure that `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` is called at all in the Swift version? Could it be that you forgot to e.g. set the app delegate's name in the Swift version? To check, add some logging code to the Swift `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` as well.

Also, make sure to add `@objc` to the Swift app delegate class (if it isn't already) and try (this is a really long shot) adding the `dynamic` keyword to the delegate methods.

And try replacing `UIApplication.sharedApplication()` with `application` (another long shot).